# UINavigationController Custom CATransition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to make a custom transition to push a view controller into the stack.

I dont know if there is an easy way to "lock" the navigationBar on its position and make the transition under the navigationBar.

I am using the following code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

First I tried the kCATransitionPush, but I could see the navigationBar moving down... so I tested kCATransitionMoveIn and it feels a bit better, but still not the way I wanted...

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not how you do custom navigation controller transitions. You have to use the iOS 7 custom animator protocols (e.g. UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning).

Comment: Here's my own example code. In this particular example I bring the new view controller's view in from the side, not the top, but it is obvious how to adjust it to do what you're after. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p301customAnimation4/NavCustomPushTest/AppDelegate.m